# VIDIOC_STREAMON error 28, No space left on device ,after i tried the common solution on the web

Tags: camera, bandwidth, depth, uvc, asus-xtion

I have a depth camera(XTION2). 
i can successfully get the image stream by the following code:

```
roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/depth/image_raw
```

but when i tried output my rgb image stream by the following code

```
roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_raw
```

I got an error message:

```
VIDIOC_STREAMON error 28, No space left on device
```

I tried some common solutions to solve this problem like:

```
sudo rmmod uvcvideo
sudo modprobe uvcvideo quirks=640
```

or

```
sudo rmmod uvcvideo
sudo modprobe uvcvideo quirks=128
```

but it still doesn't work.

my ubuntu version is "16.04"
Here's the output of "lsusb"

```
Bus 002 Device 032: ID 0b05:182c ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 031: ID 0b05:182d ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 030: ID 0bda:0401 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:e007 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5769 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 0bda:5401 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL 8153 USB 3.0 hub with gigabit ethernet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here's the output of "lsusb -t" when i plug in my xtion2 camera

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 30, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 31, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 31, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 31, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 31, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 5000M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 32, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 5000M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 32, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 16, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 11, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 11, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtsx_usb, 480M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

Can anyone help me fix this issue?please help me,thanks very much!

Answer (score -1):

i fix this issue occasionally.
after run the following code

```
sudo rmmod uvcvideo
sudo modprobe uvcvideo quirks=640
```

I pluged my xtion2 device into my computer through the port of usb2.0 from usb 3 port, and it suddenly worked. I don't konw why.

Comment: Did you manage to get higher RGB resolutions than VGA with USB2.0?
I'm currently struggling with the same issue, and plugging it into USB2.0 port removes all possible high resolution modes (getSupportedVideoModes) in OpenNI.